# Intermittent network failures, limited to certain client subnets

Tags: networking, ssh, samba, intermittent

We've been seeing intermittent network failures. The failure mode tends to be that long running connections tend to drop out. We see it most with ssh and samba connections, although some occasional http failures happen as well.

On the subnets that have these failures, we've been running a test that seems to correlate, and that's the time to form a ssh connection to the server. On affected subnets, where users also report problems, one in four attempts to open a ssh connection is exactly five or ten seconds longer than would be expected.

Is there a likely cause for why this type of failure would happen?

Comment: What kind of traffic you have noticed on particular subnet where you are facing this intermittent issue? Put some n/w traffic identifier which can tell what kind of traffic generating from particular subnet. I faced the same issue and used wireshark and it was helpful you can put this before the switch/gw of subnet and check.

Comment: What should we look for as a suspicious packets? I'm seeing a lot of dropped TCP connections, but that seems obvious.

Comment: Trace particular system and its packets and check for the destination for which you are suspecting the intermittent issue.